# Can I import OneSignal tokens to FCM?

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, onesignal

I have several thousand OneSignal **web push** notification tokens I want to import to FCM. Is there a way to do this?

I see this endpoint which requires the `https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send/...key...` endpoint that OneSignal gives me, but I don't know what to put in for `auth` and `p256dh`.

https://developers.google.com/instance-id/reference/server#create_registration_tokens_for_apns_tokens

Comment: Can you please tag the question with iOS or Android, thanks.

Comment: I'm actually referring to web push notifications, sorry I should have mentnioned

Comment: Ah, thanks for updating the question!

Comment: Hey did you ever figure this out? Running into the same issue

Comment: I don't think you can. I tried all the endpoints etc, and I got close but it says the token is invalid for the other token (forgot what it is called), which makes it obvious the token is signed with the original key, and they can't be shared

Comment: @Tallboy are you 100% sure you can't? Seems to me it's not possible so that companies don't sell their users to others. Tag me when you come up with anything, thank you.

Comment: You can pull the auth and p256dh keys from their API when you export users.

Comment: Do you have your code you used to actually get them to import? Any time I tried I got errors which lead me to believe it wasnt possible

Comment: @Dan did you manage to do that in the end?

Comment: @jiroch Put my procedure for this in the answer

Comment: @CedricHadjian Check Answer

Comment: @Dan I replied, figured it out after several days of research

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So yes this can be done. First you will need to contact OneSignal support and get the public and private VAPID keys for your app. Each app in your dashboard will have a different set.

Next you will need to make an API call to OneSignal in order to export the users in a CSV file.

You can find the API url in the docs and use curl or use your favorite language. I used Node + Axios to make my calls. The API call will supply you with a link to download the CSV.

Here is the documentation https://documentation.onesignal.com/reference#csv-export

You want to make sure you add the "extra_fields" parameter to your request with the "web_auth" and "web_p256" fields added. The CSV will provide you with the other piece of the puzzle which is the endpoint url in their identifier column.

Once you have all this information you can now send pushes using a library such as web-push for Node

https://github.com/web-push-libs/web-push

Hope that helps!

EDIT

As Cedric stated the actual push payload is a little bit more complicated because you need to comply with the OneSignal Service worker data handling.

You can see the formatting starting at line 313 [here](https://github.com/OneSignal/OneSignal-Website-SDK/blob/master/src/service-worker/ServiceWorker.ts)

If you are using a library like [web-push](https://github.com/web-push-libs/web-push) for Node to send your push payloads your payload would be formatted something like this for a standard push to a OneSignal service worker.

```
const uuidv1 = require('uuid/v1')
const webpush = require('web-push') 

let subscription = {
    endpoint: 'USER ENDPOINT URL',
    keys: {
        auth: 'USER AUTH KEY',
        p256dh: 'USER P256 KEY'
    }
}

let vapid = { private: 'VAPID PRIVATE KEY', public: 'VAPID PUBLIC KEY' }

// Format Message for OneSignal Service Worker
let notification = JSON.stringify({
    custom: {
        i: uuidv1(), //Generate UUID for the OneSignal Service worker to consume
        u: 'CLICK URL'
    },
    title: 'TOP TITLE',
    alert: 'MESSAGE BODY',
    icon: 'ICON IMAGE URL'
})

webpush.setVapidDetails('mailto: sendError@YourEmail.com', vapid.public, vapid.private)
webpush.sendNotification(subscription, notification)
```

Answer (score 1):

It's much more complex than Dan's answer. If your users don't subscribe to your own service worker, it won't work. OS will send its default notification when an 'unknown' error occurs, which it will send "You have new updates" as a notification to the user even though you passed different payload. You also need to pass: `"custom": { "i": uuidv1() }` to your payload for it to work. (don't forget to install uuid first through npm and call it). Check out [this](https://github.com/OneSignal/OneSignal-Website-SDK/blob/master/src/service-worker/ServiceWorker.ts) link and you'll figure out what other payload props you need to pass.

Comment: Ya there is a bit more involved. Luckily the formatting is pretty straightforward. I added some sample code to my answer below.